# Focus key custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, focus

I created a custom keyboard using KeyboardView and I want to activate the delete button when it is focused on it. A user might type letter a, keep his finger pressed to the screen and slide to the delete button. I want then the delete button to erase the content. I really don't know how to do that...

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: If this is about how to delete content when user presses delete button on keyboard , you can directly erase the last entered character on delete button click , though deletion in custom keyboard is not that simple, Cursor can be anywhere  so need to be careful about that .
https://github.com/PiSolve/CustomKeyBoard/blob/master/CustomKeyBoardLayout.java
This is my custom keyboard file which handles click of all keys .Its not complete yet (layout file is not there etc etc ),but it can answer your delete button handling query.

Comment: i can delete easily the content but the problem is that when i press o for instance and slide to delete with the finger still pressed on screen, delete button doesnt activate although it detected the focus of my finger on the delete button.